# how to find out a script has been added in wordpress back-end?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on admin panel for wordpress, I need to add my styles and scripts into admin panel.
e.g.

```
function framework_js () {
    wp_register_script('jq_js', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/js/jquery.jqtransform.js', array('jquery'), true);
    wp_register_script('fk_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fk-script.js');

    wp_enqueue_script('jq_js');
    wp_enqueue_script('fk_script');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'framework_js');
```

---

```
function framework_css() {
    wp_register_style('jq_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqtransform.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('jq_css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'framework_css');`
```

The issue that I wnat to know is:
How can I check these script have been added or not, is possible to use FireBug, if so? how??
Or is there and other way???

Thanks in advance

Comment: With `css` files, it is simple, you can see in the view whether your css styles have been applied. With `javascript` files, add `console&&console.log('some javascript is loaded')` line before or after the file,and check that fact in `console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webkit you can check the Network or Resources tab of the developer tools. The network tab is shown below.

[image]

Firebug has similar functionality.

[image]

You could also just check the page source for the `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the `<head>`.

Comment: thanks 4 ur A. now I can see my scripts and styles have been added. but there is a problem. those scripts and styles do not work in wordpress back-end(in this case admin panel). should I change my codes??

Comment: I can't speak to fixes for your wordpress plugin code (I do not use wordpress); I can only answer the original question. Perhaps it is best to create this follow-up as a new question here on SO.